# Powershell 5.1: unable to sort extracted XML attribute names with Get-Unique

Tags: xml, powershell-5.0

I am trying to extract all unique values stored in attribute `className` of `<input>` element from the below sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <input name="reutersIn" className="com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput">
        <useOutputMarketConfig>true</useOutputMarketConfig>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <archiveOnly>true</archiveOnly>
    </input>

    <input name="fidessaIn" className="com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput">
        <useOutputMarketConfig>true</useOutputMarketConfig>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <archiveOnly>true</archiveOnly>
    </input>

    <input name="iceIn" className="com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput">
        <useOutputMarketConfig>true</useOutputMarketConfig>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <archiveOnly>true</archiveOnly>
    </input>
</config>
```

As seen in the above XML file sample, the `className` attribute with the same value occurs 3 times.

I tried to extract `className` values and display only unique one with this:

```
[xml]$file = get-content C:\ps_scripts\configs\test.xml


$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("//input")
Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {
    
        Echo $xmlProperty.className | Get-Unique
    }
```

However, when I run the script I get the same className value printed 3 times instead of expected 1 time:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\xml2.ps1
com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput
com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput
com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput
```

How do I properly display unique `className` values in this situation?

The ultimate purpose of the script is to traverse through multiple XML files and extract all unique `className` values that are within `<input>` element (I do not know what `className` values are stored in most of the files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just change

```
$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("//input")
Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {
    
        Echo $xmlProperty.className | Get-Unique
    }
```

to

```
$xmlProperties = $input.SelectNodes("//input") | Get-Unique
Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {      
        echo $xmlProperty.className 
    }
```

Output:

```
com.ib.feed.csv.TarCsvFileInput
```